# How to install Stripe library on Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, stripe-payments

I have run the following command to install Stripe on Yii2:

```
composer require stripe/stripe-php
```

The Stripe documentation states to create a config.php file calling the library like this:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
```

However it does not worked, so I changed to

```
require_once('../vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Stripe.php');
```

And I got the following error:

> yii\base\View::main(): Failed opening required '../vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Stripe.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php')"

Any idea of how to call this Stripe library from Yii2?

Comment: How are you calling (not loading) it?

Comment: still you founded any solution on this?, because I am facing same

Comment: The solution is on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151323/how-to-integrate-stripe-payments-into-yii2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii 2 composer automatically autoloads extension so you don't have to add `require`.

You can simply use library like:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey();
```

or with namespace `use`:

```
use Stripe\Stripe;

// ...
Stripe::setApiKey();
```

Comment: Thanks, it actually automatically autoloads the Stripe library.

Comment: tried but not worked, still any other solution on this?, because I am facing same

Comment: require_once(Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext').'/stripe/init.php');
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(###############); try this code